# jq : mapping array in object to another object while keeping parent keys and adding new ones

Tags: json, jq

I would like to map the following structure

```
{
    "id" : "OUTER_ID",
    "name" : "OUTER_NAME"
    "items" : [ 
        {   
            "id" : "INNER_ID_1",
            "name" : "INNER_NAME_1",
        },
        {   
            "id" : "INNER_ID_2",
            "name" : "INNER_NAME_2",
        }
    ]   
}
```

into this

```
{
    "payload": [
        {   
            "key" : "INNER_NAME_1_KEY",
            "data" : { 
                "id" : "OUTER_ID",
                "name" : "OUTER_NAME",
                "items" : [ 
                    {   
                        "id" : "INNER_ID_1",
                        "name" : "INNER_NAME_1"
                    }   
                ]   
            }   
        },  
        {   
            "key" : "INNER_NAME_2_KEY",
            "data" : { 
                "id" : "OUTER_ID",
                "name" : "OUTER_NAME",
                "items" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "INNER_ID_2",
                        "name" : "INNER_NAME_2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So, for each item in the initial `items` array, I want to create an entry in the output's `payload`, i.e I want to map `items[i]` to `payload[i].data.items` while also creating the `payload`, `key` and `data` keys in the output, and setting `payload[i].data.id` and `payload[i].data.name` to the input's outer `id` and `name`.

Can this be done with jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the following filter :

```
.id as $id | .name as $name | {payload : [ .items[] | {key:.id, data:{id:$id, name: $name, items:[.]}} ] }
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/zq8CfS2Wab).

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!